# How to communicate between different instance of same service in .Net?

Tags: asp.net-core, cloud, microservices, pcf

I have a microservice hosted in PCF cloud. Sometimes this microservice is scaled up to 2 or 3 instances, now how I can communicate or listen between these instances. Let say, some action happened in instance 1, should be communicated to instance 2 and instance 3.

I guess, in Java we can use spring cloud bus to achieve this. How we can achieve the same in .Net?

Comment: The question is too vague. You need to share the context and problem.

Comment: Yes. Need to have use case. There are many solutions. Like service bus, message bus, rabbit mq. Or you can use redis or even kafka. Need to know exact use case.

Comment: Use Case: We have a RabbitMQ consumer created using IHostedService, which will always look for messages to consume from queue. Now if there is any failure occurs while consuming message, we don't want to consume further, so we will stop the hosted service. 
Considering this scenario, if I have 2 to 4 instances, how can I stop the hosted service for all the instances at one shot?